# MDX Query with parameters with multiples values and null value

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube

I work with a SSAS Cube and Datazen (dashboard creator). I've a data view (for the valueCode 'AZE') with 3 parameters:

**AgeClassCode**: 'AGE01', 'AGE02', 'AGE03', ...

**StatutCode**: 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ...

**NiveauCode**: 'X', 'Y', 'W', ...

With this query, when I use multiple values or just one value for each, it works. 
But I would like that the query returns all values for a parameter when the parameter's value is null. I've tested ISEMPTY(@param), ISEMPTY(STRTOSET(@param)), ... but that returns this error:

> An mdx expression was expected. An empty expression was specified.

This query works for one or more values:

```
   SELECT 
   NON EMPTY 
   { 
        [Measures].[Value], [Measures].[PreviousValueYear], [Measures].[PreviousValueReportMonth] 
   } ON COLUMNS, 
   NON EMPTY 
   { 
        NONEMPTY
        (
            [EntiteFederal].[ServiceCode].[ServiceCode].ALLMEMBERS *
            [EntiteFederal].[EntiteCode].[EntiteCode].ALLMEMBERS *
            [ReportMonth].[ReportMonth].[ReportMonth].ALLMEMBERS *
            [T].[Year].[Year].ALLMEMBERS 
        ) 
    } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
    FROM
    ( 
            SELECT ( { [ValueType].[ValueCode].&[AZE] } ) ON COLUMNS 
            FROM (
                    SELECT ( STRTOSET('{{ @AgeClassCode }}') ) ON COLUMNS 
                    FROM ( 
                            SELECT ( STRTOSET('{{ @NiveauCode }}') ) ON COLUMNS 
                            FROM 
                            ( 
                                SELECT ( (STRTOSET('{{ @StatutCode }}') ) ON COLUMNS 
                                FROM [MyCube]
                            )
                        )
                )
    )                       
    WHERE 
    ( 

        IIF( STRTOSET('{{ @StatutCode }}').Count = 1, STRTOSET('{{ @StatutCode }}'), [Statut].[StatutCode].currentmember ),
        IIF( STRTOSET('{{ @NiveauCode }}').Count = 1, STRTOSET('{{ @NiveauCode }}'), [Niveau].[NiveauCode].currentmember ),
        IIF( STRTOSET('{{ @AgeClassCode }}').Count = 1, STRTOSET('{{ @AgeClassCode }}'), [AgeClass].[AgeClassCode].currentmember ),
        [ValueType].[ValueCode].&[AZE]
     )
```

What do I have to change?

**EDIT:**

To test the strtoset()

, the good solution is the

```
isError()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `strToSet` or `strToMember` you need to supply a string that represents valid `mdx` so for example these are ok:

```
strToSet("[AgeClassCode].[AgeClassCode].members")

strToMember("[AgeClassCode].[AgeClassCode].[AGE01]")
```

This isn't valid as `NULL` isn't a string, or something that represents mdx:

```
strToSet(NULL)
```

So if in your client you'd like NULL to represent all members then somehow you need to transform the NULL to a string "[AgeClassCode].[AgeClassCode].members" before it hits `strToSet`.

Comment: There is no way to change it, in the software, it's selection list navigator based on my dimension. The error appears when no value is selected. 
I've also try to change the parameter AgeClassCode like this:  

`IIF(ISEMPTY('{{ @AgeClassCode }}'), [AgeClass].[AgeClassCode].Members,STRTOSET('{{ @AgeClassCode }}')) `


And i've deleted the where clause, but still the same error.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've not played with the interface of datazen. You need to feed valid MDX strings into strToSet or strToMember - so if you want nothing then try feeding in `{}` or if you want every member then something like `[AgeClassCode].[AgeClassCode].[AgeClassCode].members`. Feeding NULL into strToSet, strToMember or ISEMPTY will all fail. ISEMPTY needs a valid mdx expression as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we're going through the same problem, but I think it is, and I've found a solution, for mine so let me share it with you, im using pentaho mondrian btw.

```
IIF( STRTOSET('{{ @StatutCode }}').Count = 1, 
   STRTOSET('{{ @StatutCode }}'), 
   [Statut].[StatutCode].currentmember 
)
```

this hasn't worked for me, given that the parameter doesn't exist the query won't work.

What I've found was that, given the parameter is empty the query would be like

```
IIF('@VALUE(:StatutCode)' = '',
    [Statut].[StatutCode].currentmember,
    [Statut].[@VALUE(:StatutCode)]
)
```

so given your parameter exists if will compare 'statuscode' = '' and if doesnt it will compare '' = ''

hope it helps